# One way data binding with Vue-JS v-model

Tags: vue.js, twig, symfony4

I am working with Symfony twig and Vue.JS. All is working fine when I persist the form the first time... But when I want to edit the form, the symfony controller is sending variables which Vue.JS “v-model” attribute does not recognize and the form fields are not filled in with values sent by Symfony...

Would there be a way to use the Vue.js v-model with just one way data binding, momentarily (during the loading of the web page for example)… so when the form is rendering, Vue.JS doesn’t interfere with data transfer from Twig and Controller symfony ?

Thanks for your response !

**Here is the code of PHP Symfony controler rendering form :**

```
return $this->render('gestionContratInterimaire/modification.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'GestionContratInterimaireController',
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'contratInterimaire' => $contratInterimaire
    ]);
```

**Here is the code of HTML Twig form:**

```
<Ajoutcontratinterimaire :coef-agence="{{ contratInterimaire.getCoefficientAgence }}" inline-template>
<div class="container">

        <div>
            {{ form_start(form) }}
                {{form_row(form.idInterimaire)}}
                {{form_row(form.idAgence)}}
                {{form_row(form.Motif_Contrat)}}
                 <div v-if="remplacementIsChecked">
                    {{form_row(form.Personne_Remplacee)}}
                </div>
                {{form_row(form.Coefficient_Agence)}}
                {{form_row(form.Salaire_Horaire_Hors_Coeff)}}
                {{form_row(form.Cout_Horaire_Avec_Coeff)}}
                {{form_row(form.Date_Debut)}}
                {{form_row(form.cancel)}}
                {{form_row(form.submit)}}
            {{ form_end(form) }}

        </div>
```

**And here is the code for the Vue.JS variable:**

```
->add('Cout_Horaire_Avec_Coeff', NumberType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    "v-model" => "avecCoefSalaireValue",
                    "@blur" => "calculValue()",
                ]
```

**Diagram of Vue.JS data binding :**

[VUE.JS - V-Model Data Binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ypnJ.png)

Comment: Please add the code snippets to your post (Instead of attaching the images), so people can help you properly. And it will be a good reference for the users later.

Comment: You're right, thanks for the tip !